# How do I restart a Group of Servers through PowerShell, that have different Credentials, and wait for them to be up again?

Tags: powershell

I have some Servers grouped up in a variable like this:

```
Name     Credential                                Type Group
----     ----------                                ---- -----
HV08     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    2 A    
HV03     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    2 A
HV07     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    2 B    
HV04     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    2 B
HV06     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    2 B
HV05     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    2 B
HV01     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    2 B
HVTEST   System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    2 B
HV02     System.Management.Automation.PSCredential    2 C
```

Some of those have different Admin credentials than others. Some have the same. They are saved in the `Credential` Property

I need to restart them, depending on their group, and all servers of one group should be restarted together.

Normally I would do it like this (the `-Wait` parameter does all the magic):

```
foreach ($Group in $RestartGroups) {
    $OriginalObject = $Group.Group
    Restart-Computer -ComputerName $OriginalObject.Name -Credential $OriginalObject.Credential -Force -Wait
}
```

However, I can't pass an array to the `Credential` Parameter, and even if I somehow could, they don't have the same credentials.

How can I restart Servers in groups that have different credentials, and wait for the groups to be up again, before going to the next group?

Comment: You have 3 groups, so you could start 3 Jobs, restarting each group using `-Wait` and then wait for the 3 Jobs to complete.

Comment: Hashtable with the ID and credentials and iterate through them :)

Comment: If the servers of one group have each different credentials and you need to restart them all together then instead of `-Wait` you would probably need a custom function using something like `Test-Connection` or `Test-NetConnection`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon yeah i'll do the custom function thing. darn, the `-wait` was really comfortable and reliable. hoped I didn't have to `test-connection` or background job it myself

Comment: I have something you could use, I can post in answer but what would you like to test to know if servers are up (TCP or ICMP)?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon i don't really care as long as it works ;-). but i guess tcp would be a bit nicer

Answer (score 1):

Let's see, I think this ***should*** work, but is hard to tell without testing it :P

Try it and let me know.

- **First we define the custom function to test connectivity**

```bash
function Test-Port {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string] $Name,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, Position = 0)]
        [int[]] $Port,

        [Parameter()]
        [switch] $Detailed,

        [Parameter()]
        [int] $TimeOut = 5
    )

    process {
        foreach($i in $port) {
            $response = [ordered]@{
                ServerName = $Name
                Port       = $i
            }

            try {
                $testPort = [System.Net.Sockets.TCPClient]@{
                    SendTimeout = [timespan]::FromSeconds($TimeOut).TotalMilliseconds
                }
                $message = $null
                $testPort.Connect($Name, $i)
                $response.TestConnection = $testPort.Connected
            }
            catch {
                $response.TestConnection = $testPort.Connected
                $message = $_.Exception.InnerException.Message
            }
            finally {
                if($testPort) {
                    $testPort.Dispose()
                }
            }

            if($Detailed.IsPresent) {
                $response.Message = $message
            }

            [pscustomobject] $response
        }
    }
}
```

**This function will return an object that looks like this:**

```
PS /> $serverArray.Name | Test-Port -Port 3389

ServerName Port TestConnection
---------- ---- --------------
HV08       3389          False
HV03       3389          False
HV07       3389          False
HV04       3389          False
HV06       3389          False
....
....
```

- Now, I have recreated your initial object containing **server names** and **creds** and stored it in `$serverArray`, change this variable to your variable name.

```bash
# Group the servers by `Group` property
$serverArray | Group-Object Group | ForEach-Object {
    foreach($computer in $_.Group) {
        # Restart each computer on this group
        $restartComputerSplat = @{
            ComputerName = $computer.Name
            Credential   = $computer.Credential
            Force        = $true
        }

        Restart-Computer @restartComputerSplat
    }

    # Wait 1 minute and let computers start the reboot process
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 60

    do {
        # Sleep for your call here, using 30 seconds.
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 30

        # Use a port that you know is Open, using RDP as example here
        $res = $_.Group.Name | Test-Port -Port 3389
    }
    while($res.TestConnection -contains $false)
}
```